# How To Make ActiveAdmin Load Particular Data For Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

This is what I want. I have table called some `x` and I added this table in Active Admin Page. What happens after I added is that it loads all the data in that table for index page. But I want to load only data that are true for some conditions.

Say for example table `x` has one column called `val` and the values in the table are `val(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`. I want to only load values that are greater than 5. How to do this in Active Admin?

Comment: have you checkedout this http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `scoped_collection` method.
For this in AR model create a scope:

```
scope :greater_then_five, -> { where("some_attribute >= ?", 5) } # any condition you need
```

And then simply use this scope in AA:

```
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      MyModel.greater_then_five
    end
  end
```

This way you'll have the data fetched from database and used by AA filtered.